# Почему зависает форма при работе с потоком в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, delphi-7

Не подскажите почему виснет? (код выполняется, но форма зависает)
Или можно другим способом посылать запросы с рандомной задержкой?

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdCookieManager, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket,
  IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, ExtCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TNewThread = class(TThread)
    private
    Progress: string;
    procedure SetProgress;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TNewThread.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(SetProgress);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewThread: TNewThread;
begin
  NewThread:=TNewThread.Create(False);
  NewThread.Priority:=tpNormal;
  NewThread.Resume;
  NewThread.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
end;

procedure TNewThread.SetProgress;
var
  list, lista: TStringList;
  int, i: Integer;
  s, b: string;
  resul: string;
begin
...другой ненужный код...

    resul := Form1.IdHTTP1.Get('https://...');
    while Pos('images/icons/tb_stocked', resul) > 0 do begin
      lista := TStringList.Create;
      lista.Add('...');
      Form1.IdHTTP1.Post('https://...',lista);
      Sleep(10000);
      lista.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

Форма зависает, потому что вы делаете всю работу внутри вызова `Synchronize`. Тем самым, вы отказываетесь от всего того, что поток может вам дать и по сути выполняете его в главном потоке (в котором же и весь GUI работает).

Учитесь работать с потоками - их суть и сила в том, чтобы выполнять основной объем работы в фоне, а в главный поток рапортовать только результаты. Поищите туториал.